# How to do a regex compare of string values in 2 columns in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

So let’s say I have 2 columns, both containing string values,
ColA , ResultCol

I want to check if In a row, the string in ColA is a substring of string in ResultCol

I know about ‘`WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(col, regex)`’ , but how do I do this comparison with string in another column?

Please let me know if I missed explaining any criteria of the question

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @jokol, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use [like](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#comparison_operators) operator in BigQuery which will compare the strings of two columns.I have created a sample table Product and ran the below code:

**Code**

```
SELECT * from `project.dataset.Product` where product like concat('%',country,'%')
```

**Sample Table**

[image]

**Output**

[image]